# Anyone who are good with Drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm sitting here trying to learn about drag and drop - (not that it is anything especially hard) but one thing is really on my nerves: i'm following this

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

I don't understand why the elements (in this case the images) stacks when dragged on top of each other: is there any way that i can prevent this from happening ? so that nothing happens when someone tries to drag an drag-able element on top of another drag-able element - hope someone has time to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might help if i try to explain what i want to create

I would like to create this
[What i want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztil2.jpg)

A list with different elements which can be draged back and forth to the drag area - depending on what the user wants: the elements should how ever not be able to be draged on each other as one of the elements then would disapere

Step two is then to write something that understands which elements the drag area holds and then use PHP to send me an email with the names of the elements chossen by the user - but that is something compleatly difference :D

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
/*
if($("#div1").has(".drag-img").length)){

}
*/
```

```css
 #element-box{
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #333333;
  height: 50px;
  width:50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 20px;
 }

 #div1{
      width:400px;
      height:70px;
      padding:20px;
      border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
    }

    #drag1{
    background: red;
    }

    #drag2{
    background: blue;
    }

    #drag3{
    background: green;
    }

    #drag4{
    background: orange;
    }

    #drag5{
    background: hotpink;
    }
```

```html
<div id="element-box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img class="drag-img" id="drag1" src="img/one.jpg" draggable="true"
ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
<div id="element-box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img class="drag-img" id="drag2" src="img/two.jpg" draggable="true"
ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
<div id="element-box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img class="drag-img" id="drag3" src="img/three.jpg" draggable="true"
ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
<div id="element-box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img class="drag-img" id="drag4" src="img/four.jpg" draggable="true"
ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
<div id="element-box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img class="drag-img" id="drag5" src="img/five.jpg" draggable="true"
ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see where the confusion is coming from. In the future, I suggest learning from multiple sources of information, so that you may learn what the lesson may be forgetting to cover.

In the way the example was originally written, attributes were added to the div to allow it to have the 'draggable' content be 'dropped' upon it. Here's an excerpt of the code in the example, followed by a commented line to explain both attributes used.

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
```

The working attributes are:

- `ondrop="drop(event)` Which executes the 'event' when the element is dropped
- `ondragover="allowDrop(event)"` Which allows the 'drop' to happen.

---

The crux of the lesson here is that the ability for a div to have something 'dropped' on it is *something that has been allowed to have that ability*. In other words: If it doesn't have the necessary attributes to execute the script's behavior, it won't be allowed (because the 'drop' conditions, meaning the 'dragged' element is being 'dropped' on an element with the... 
 `ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"` 
...attributes set appropriately, have not been met)

I've decided to keep and edit this example and add to the level of demonstration because you're already familiar with it. Some things to keep in mind:

- Notice how if the Kitten were to be 'dropped' on an 'invalid' element, the red highlighting stays. This is to show that the scripting here completed the '`drag`' function, but not the '`drop`' function. The '`drag`' creates the red effects, the '`drop`' hides them. The script does this by changing the appropriate CSS properties for said effects.
- I've provided multiple Codepen examples to show the utilization of the different tabs/windows, contrasting with the W3Schools example (to be thorough and demonstrate how it would look without the usage of the 'script" or "style" tags).
- I've decided to use the most basic code possible in the script, like setting the CSS properties for each div separately, and repeating usage of the same variable. I wouldn't recommend writing it like this in anything except experiments.
- I've added comments inside to help you see what each of the tougher parts do.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwdgbY

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqpJjo

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey :D 
And thansk for your help - i totally follow your drift and how you have created and area in which nothing can de draged and droped in :)

But that was i problem i wasent even aware of :) - the thing i was trying to come arround was - if we now have two pictures of kittens, then how can we create it so that the one picture cant be placed on top of the other - and thereby disapere ? 


and - wouldn't it be easyer to just declare that #div1 wouldent accept drop events ? :D and seriously thanks for taking you time to help me

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not going to write your code for you. I wanted to help you understand the problem at hand, not provide a solution for you for free. I would suggest checking out some resources that show you how to change HTML attributes with Javascript. Write the code for that behavior and put it into the events you have, disallowing the 'stacking' of the draggable elements. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp
Please don't have any diagrams with "Write me!" in them again. This isn't a free labor site.

Comment: Chil :D diddent ask for you to write it - would be pointless for my learning: it is afterall only a freetime thing. just wondered if there were a way to say that the dropevent shouldn't be working for <img> tags